# Test and color cells of specific columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking at a Range in Excel, then if I see "Yes" in a cell, coloring all cells in the range Yellow.

Now I would like to tweak the Fixed Range and look at the each column header and *only* perform this coloring based on the suffixes that I say. In this case, I would like to do this evaluation on the columns ending in "_ty".

Code to color the entire range of cells:

```vb
Sub ColorCellRange()

    Dim c As Range

    ' Loop through all cells in range A1:E + last used Row in column A
    For Each c In Range("A1:E" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

        'Look for Yes
        If InStr(1, c.Text, "Yes", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

            'Color the cell RED
            c.Offset(0, 0).Interior.Color = vbYellow

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Current output:
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using conditional formatting?

Comment: Main reason there could be 1 worksheet this month and 5 the next month.  I will wrap code around this module to go through each sheet that is present.    Something like:    ``` Sub all_sheet()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
        For Each ws In Worksheets
            Call ColorCellRange
    Next
End Sub```

Comment: Sub all_sheet()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
            For Each ws In Worksheets
            ws.Activate
            Call ColorCellRange
    Next
End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Option Compare Text  
Sub ColorCellRange()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("A1:E" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        If c.Value Like "*Yes*" And Cells(1, c.Column).Value Like "*_ty" Then
            c.Offset(0, 0).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

or you can remove `Option Compare Text` and convert `.value` to low/upper case:

```
Sub ColorCellRange()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("A1:E" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        If LCase(c.Value) Like "*yes*" And _
            LCase(Cells(1, c.Column).Value) Like "*_ty" Then
            c.Offset(0, 0).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!  This worked well and I was able to wrap around my code to perform on multiple sheets.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach: scan the column headers and decide if to process the cells below.

```vb
Sub ColorCellRange()

    Dim c As Range, hdr As Range, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet  'or whatever
    'loop over all headers in Row 1
    For Each hdr In ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
        
        If hdr.Value Like "*_ty" Then 'is this a header we're interested in ?
            For Each c In ws.Range(hdr.Offset(1), ws.Cells(Rows.Count, hdr.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
                If InStr(1, c.Text, "Yes", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    c.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                End If
            Next c
        End If                        ' like "_ty"
    Next hdr
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this is how I was originally trying to solve the problem myself but was struggling.  I ran your code as well and it worked perfectly.  Thank you for sharing this.